# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storage type 'plocal' is different by storage type in URL

Tags: orientdb2.2

I am a new user of OrientDB. I tried to use OrientDB Console to create a new database. The steps I followed are from OrientDB official site: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Create-Database.html. But I got errors.

1) run OrientDB server on the local PC: bin/server.bat

2) run console: bin/console.bat

3) connect to remote server:

```
orientdb> CONNECT remote:localhost root root
```

4) create a new database and then comes the error:

```
orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}> CREATE DATABASE REMOTE:localhost/myremotetestdb root root PLOCAL

Creating database [REMOTE:localhost/myremotetestdb] using the storage type 
[plocal]...
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storage type 'plocal' is 
different by storage type in URL

orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}>
```

Comment: Looks like this is the source code. if it is true, it would be really confusing.   
if (!databaseURL.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith(storageType))
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Storage type '" + storageType + "' is different by storage type in URL");

Comment: using lower case can fix this problem:　CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/myremotetestdb root root plocal

Comment: I have raised the issue to orientdb dev team.  They have fixed to support upper case on 2.2.32.  https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7923